# Intersection of the tautological bundle with a fiber of a geometrically ruled surface

Tags: algebraic-surfaces

I'm reading Beauville's book, Complex Algebraic Surfaces, and I'm trying to understand an affirmation in a proposition that characterizes the Picard group of a geometrically ruled surface.

First, let $S= \mathbb{P}_C(E)$ be a geometrically ruled surface over a curve $C$, $p: S \rightarrow C$ the structure map. The tautological bundle is constructed as the cokernel of the inclusion $i: N \rightarrow p^*E$, where $N$ is the line bundle such that $N_s$ is the line corresponding to $s$ at $E_{p(s)}$. That is , we have the exact sequence

$$0 \rightarrow N \rightarrow p^*E \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_S(1) \rightarrow 0 $$

Then, there is a proposition: if $H$ is the divisor corresponding to $\mathcal{O}_S(1)$, then
$$\mathrm{Pic}(S) = p^* \mathrm{Pic}(C) \oplus \mathbb{Z} \cdot H $$

My problem with this proof is with its first affirmation: if $F$ is a fiber of $p$, then $F \cdot H = 1$. I know that $F \cdot H = \deg (H|_F)$. As $F\simeq \mathbb{P}^1$, I bet that I need to prove that $\mathcal{O}_S(1)|_F = \mathcal{O}_F(1)$. I can see it if, for some embedding $S\subset \mathbb{P}^n$, in fact $\mathcal{O}_S(1)$ is the sheaf of hyperplanes. But I'm not sure about it. Is it true? Or do I need a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [**1**, Chapter II, Proposition 7.12], the surjective map of sheaves $p^*E \to \mathcal{O}_S(1)$ gives  a morphism of schemes
$C \to \mathbb{P}(E)$ over $C$, namely a section of $p \colon \mathbb{P}(E) \to C$.

Moreover, the image of this section corresponds to a divisor in $|\mathcal{O}_S(1)|$, see [$1$, Chapter V Propositions 2.6 and 2.8].

Then, every element $H \in |\mathcal{O}_S(1)|$ satisfies $HF=1$.

**Reference.**

**[1]** R. Hartshorne, *Algebraic Geometry*, Springer 1977.